# Some margin I don't know where is

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website (http://mat3.us/ba/) and as you can see If you access it there is some kind of border, I don't know, It's like the content width is not 100%, only the menu. I tried to find what It is but I couldn't.

Comment: No, I can't see that. Please explain in more detail (i.e., show us a small portion of the markup that is causing the problem, or at least tell us *exactly* which element is causing it), then we will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap. That issue happens when you don't have `container`s or `row`s nested correctly.

In your case, the issue is in `section#contact`. The first div inside `#mapa` is a `.container`, but its sibling is a `.row`. That messes up the Bootstrap grid system, and causes your layout issue.

I figured this out by going into the browser's Inspect Element, and deleting elements (in the Source Tree, you can select and element and hit Delete/Backspace to remove it) until the issue cleared up. I then Undo the delete, and delete stuff inside it. Repeat until the issue has been identified.

[This link](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) does a great job of explaining the grid system in more detail.

Comment: Thanks! There was a </div> missing.